# Internal cast of collection elements

Tags: java, collections, casting

In Java is there a way to cast the following:

`ArrayList<IMyType> list`

into

`ArrayList<MyType>`

if

`MyType implements IMyType`

?

Comment: huch .. who left the -1? :)

Comment: The [best way to understand this concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). BWT I did not downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain that all `IMyType`s in the `List` are `MyType`, you could force an unchecked conversion type variable assignment:

```
List<IMyType> l1;
List rawList = l1;
List<MyType> l2 = rawList;
```

Or

```
List<IMyType> l1;
List<MyType> l2 = (List) l1;
```

<sub>Note: this will produce a `ClassCastException` at runtime if you retrieve an element from `l2` (for instance, iterating in an [enhanced] `for` loop) and it isn't a `MyType`.</sub>

Keep in mind this is more a hack than a proper solution, and is completely bypassing type safety (which is what generics is about basically).

This could be hinting that something is not quite right with the modeling of the classes and/or how they are used.

Comment: Thank you very much .. this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you also for advise regarding type-safety. My particular problem is that I get an ArrayList out of a Java RMI method which is of type `ArrayList<IMyType>`. Then I want to use this list but without the link to the RMI-type any more (which is `IMyTxpe`) and instead use the internal representation of the list elements - which is, `MyType`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are absolutely sure that your `list` contains only instances of `MyType` (or its subtypes) then you can do something like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<MyType> myList = (List<MyType>) (List<?>) list;
```

This will first cast your list of `IMyType` to list of any type `<?>` which then you can cast to more precise type. But be sure to use it only if your `list` contains instances of `MyType` and nothing else.

Anyway this approach is very rarely used and in most cases can be replaced with

```
List<? extends IMytype>
```

or

```
List<? super MyType>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, This is because `ArrayList<MyType>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<IMyType>` . Just only `MyType` is the subtype of `IMyType`. What you can do is you can iterate the `ArrayList<IMyType>` and get the `IMyType` object and then type cast it to `MyType` instance like

```
IMyType iMyType = ..

MyType myType = (MyType)iMyType;
```

Comment: so the only way to get `ArrayList<MyType>` would be to iterate over all the elements and do a cast?

Comment: I have updated my answer :) Yes, that's is the only way

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You can't directly cast `ArrayList`. You can cast one by one

```
 ArrayList<IMyType> list=new ArrayList<IMyType>();
 ArrayList<MyType> list2=new ArrayList<MyType>();
 for(IMyType i:list){
    list2.add((MyType)i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do cast in this case: (`Inteder` extends `Number`)

```
List<IMyType> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends IMyType> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list2 = list1;
```